# Combine Text and categorical feature in LSTM model (Keras)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, lstm

I have a dataframe like:

```
Text | Topic | Label
aaaa | 1     | 0
vvv  | 2     | 0
sss  | -1    | 1
eee  | 2     | 0
...
```

I was wondering if someone knows if there is a way to use both Text and Topic (categorical variable) to predict Label.

Answer (score -1):

For the text you can use tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization and tf.keras.layers.Embedding layers to convert it to N-dimensional vector. For the topic you can use one-hot encoding.